# This is about how to initialize Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am learning about initializing the Provider used by Riverpod on [this site](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/robust-app-initialization-riverpod/#the-%E2%80%9Cold%E2%80%9D-way-provider-overrides-don%E2%80%99t-use-this).
Therefore, it is explained that the following Provider initialization is old.

```dart
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences(SharedPreferencesRef ref) =>
    throw UnimplementedError();
```

```dart
void main() async {  
  final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  runApp(ProviderScope(
    overrides: [
      sharedPreferencesProvider.overrideWithValue(sharedPreferences)
    ],
    child: const MainApp(),
  ));
}
```

The reason is, `we should not initialize dependencies inside main as we can’t recover if something goes wrong.`
But I don't understand this. What does that mean? Why can't main recover if something goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading the previous chapter "[Eager Provider Initialization with a Child Widget](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/robust-app-initialization-riverpod/#eager-provider-initialization-with-a-child-widget)". The whole point is that we can handle an unsuccessful initialization by showing an error widget and a fix button (the usual `ref.invalidate()` is used there).

If something goes wrong in the `main` function, you can affect it (e.g. via try-catch), but you can't show it to the user.

This is why it is recommended to use async initialization inside `FutureProvider` and further get the value via `ref.watch(futureProvider).requireValue` if necessary. Or use another asynchronous provider with a dependency on this (and many others) one and handle all states via `when` inside the widget.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
void main() async {  
  try {
    final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    runApp(ProviderScope(
      overrides: [
        sharedPreferencesProvider.overrideWithValue(sharedPreferences)
      ],
      child: const MainApp(),
    ));
  } catch (error) {
    print('Error during initialization: $error');
  }
}
```